# How do you override the Tuckey use-query-string setting?

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to add a query param to a redirected url like this in urlrewrite.xml:

```
<rule>
    <condition name="host">www.foo.com</condition>
    <from>^/foo/bar</from>
    <to type="redirect" last="true">http://www.bar.com/foo/bar?test=testString</to>
</rule>
```

But the request coming in has a param on it already and the resulting redirected url is this:

http://www.bar-d.mtvi.com/foo/bar?test=testString?test2=test2String

**notice the 2nd "?".**

What I want is this:
`http://www.bar-d.mtvi.com/foo/bar?test=testString&test2=test2String`

use-query-string is set to "true" in the urlrewrite element.

**Question: How do you properly pass a query string?**

Thanks for your consideration and any suggestions much appreciated!!

Comment: Hum, I have the opposite question: I have use-query-string=false, and would like to match on query string for just one rule, and rewrite the name of the parameter. I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367232/getting-the-query-string-when-using-tuckey-url-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  This was happening because I didn't close the "from" match with a "$" symbol.  Here's how it should look:

```
<rule>
    <condition name="host">www.foo-d.com</condition>
    <from>^/foo/bal(\?)?(.*)?$</from>
    <to type="redirect" last="true">http://www.bar-d.mtvi.com/foo/bar?test=testString&amp;$2</to>
</rule>
```

The only issue here is that if there is no query string on the originating request, the "to" stmt still adds an ampersand at the end of the query string.  To get past this you could create 2 rewrite rules, one that matches with a query string and the other with out.