# Getting the query string when using Tuckey URL Rewrite

Tags: java, regex, url-rewriting, urlrewriter, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have the following rule:

```
<rule>
     <from>^/users/(.*)$</from>
     <to last="true">/users.do$1</to>
</rule>
```

And I want to match the following url:

```
http://localhost:8077/users/?elemsPerPage=10
```

and redirect it to:

```
http://localhost:8077/users.do?elemsPerPage=10
```

The problem is that when the url rewriter engine finds the "?" character in the url it does not return anything else in the $1 matched parameter. Neither it adds the parameters to the query string. Any ideas?

Comment: normally this is done by adding a qsa (query-string-append) to the rule, which unfortunately seems to be not supported. Maybe adding %{QUERY_STRING} can help? But that's not tested.

Comment: Thanks for the insight I've discovered that there is a way to achieve this using variables. For the query string the good one is %{query-string}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've found a way to solve this:

Rule:

```
<rule>
     <from>^/users/$</from>
     <to last="true">/users.do?%{query-string}</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: Just what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

There is a better way, try to add use-query-string="true" in urlrewrite

`<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">`

Comment: This is the more appropriate solution.

Comment: This might be obvious, but this solution assumes that you expect this functionality for all your rewrites.

Comment: tkane2000 makes the right point here. Both are good solutions, depends on your needs. I have about 200+ rewrites to manage and I'm not about to globally apply use-query-string to them all.